# How to delete the rows from Sqlite Database in php

Tags: php, sqlite

I am new to PhP. I am trying to delete some rows from my sqlite database, but I can't figure out what is wrong. My code is as below:

```
<?php
    $app_name=array("TestApp", "MyDataBase");
    $dir = 'sqlite:/home/ravi/public_html/GcmServer/FavoriteApps.db';
    $dbh= new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($app_name);$i++) {
        error_log("looop start here...............");
        error_log("FirstAppName ".$app_name[$i]);
        $result=  $dbh->Query("DELETE FROM favorite_apps WHERE appname = '$app_name[$i]'") or die( error_log("error".mysql_error() ));
        error_log("looop execute here...............");
    }
?>
```

And my log file is like this:

```
[Wed Sep 19 11:16:38 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] looop start    here...............
[Wed Sep 19 11:16:38 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FirstAppName TestApp
[Wed Sep 19 11:16:38 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] error
```

and my localhost show 1,
thanks.

Comment: `mysql_error` cannot see errors that happened in PDO. Use [`PDO::errorInfo`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) instead. And look into prepared statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `mysql_error()` function but your database is sqlite and you are using PDO, where error handling is quite different. Try to encapsulate your code into `try-catch` block to see more info:

```
<?php
  $app_name=array("TestApp", "MyDataBase");
  $dir = 'sqlite:/home/ravi/public_html/GcmServer/FavoriteApps.db';
  $dbh= new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
  try {
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($app_name);$i++) {
      error_log("looop start here...............");
      error_log("FirstAppName ".$app_name[$i]);
      $dbh->Query("DELETE FROM favorite_apps WHERE appname = '$app_name[$i]'");
      error_log("looop execute here...............");
    }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Some additional code is required to make PDO throw exceptions: [`$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).